# How to avoid azure to close inactive app service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Even if always on flas is setted, azure closes our web apps after inactivity 20 minutes. Then it opens them when first request comes. Is it possible to avoid from this behaviour. We want our services always running and responds immediately.

App service plan is Standard: 1 Large. Subscription's offer is "Azure in Open"

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Go to the App Service Web App within the Azure Portal, navigate to the "Application Settings" section, and set the "Always On" option to "On". This will ensure the application is always running.

FYI, the "Application Settings" pane in the Azure Portal is changing to "Configuration", and is currently in Preview at the time of writing this.

Comment: it is already setted to "On". But azure still closes the web app.

Comment: @ufukvarol How do you know it "closes" the web app? Perhaps a different issue is occurring?